# Why does this equal undefined in functions in React?

Tags: reactjs

The code

```
function test() {
  console.log(this)
}
test()
```

works different in a React project and in a blank HTML page. In React it shows `undefined` while without React output is `Window`. Why does it happen?

In react I call function in App.js after everything on the last lines of the file.

Comment: You might be using strict mode for react.

Comment: Even if I call ```console.log(this)``` in the end of index.js without StrictMode, it shows undefined.